# Replace between patterns that start and end in different lines

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file with the following format:

```
Whatever1
Whatever2
Whatever3
binaries=(
text1
bin2
ohhh3
)
Whatever4
Whatever5
Whatever6
```

I need to replace whatever inside lines `binaries=(` and `)` with a command output.

I'm able to pick the following block with a command like `sed -n -e '/binaries=(/,/)/p' filename`:

```
binaries=(
text1
bin2
ohhh3
)
```

Or even better with this `awk '/binaries/,/)/{if(!/binaries|)/)print}' filename`:

```
text1
bin2
ohhh3
```

But, I have to do it rewriting the original file, and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You mean you want to keep all `Whatever*` and replace the block with output of a command?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Only the block I want to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/binaries=(/,/)/{
       //!d
       /)/e uname
     }'
```

Replace `uname` with your command.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in awk, e.g.:

```
awk '
  f && /)/ { f=0 }
  !f
  !f && /binaries=\(/ { f=1 ; p=1 }
  p { system ("your_command") ; p=0 }
'
```

where "your_command" will define the replacement.

Explanation: The flag `f` will control the state machine; if it is set you are in the block that shall be replaced. With the match of the start and end pattern the flag is changed accordingly. While you're in the block the system call will get executed; the flag `p` is used to print it just once.

To replace your original file create a new file and overwrite the original one afterwards, or use a recent version of GNU `awk` with option `-i inplace`.

Comment: This command removes `binaries=(` and `)`, that shouldn't. And an explanation of it, will be great.

Comment: @jherran; I fixed it, and now it will keep the enclosing patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for simplicity, I accept the other answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem.